# How to read field from nested json?

Tags: json, pyspark

this is my test json file.

```
{
  "item" : {
    "fracData" : [ ],
    "fractimeData" : [ {
      "number" : "1232323232",
      "timePeriods" : [ {
        "validFrom" : "2021-08-03"
      } ]
    } ],
    "Module" : [ ]
  }
}
```

This is how I read the json file.

```
starhist_test_df = spark.read.json("/mapr/xxx/yyy/ttt/dev/rawdata/Test.json", multiLine=True)
starhist_test_df.createOrReplaceTempView("v_test_df")
```

This query works.

```
df_test_01 = spark.sql("""
 select item.fractimeData.number from v_test_df""")
df_test_01.collect();
```

Result

```
[Row(number=['1232323232'])]
```

But this query doesn't work.

```
df_test_01 = spark.sql("""
 select item.fractimeData.timePeriods.validFrom from v_test_df""")
df_test_01.collect();
```

Error

```
cannot resolve 'v_test_df.`item`.`fractimeData`.`timePeriods`['validFrom']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''validFrom'' is of string type.; line 3 pos 0;
```

What do I have to change, to read the validFrom field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dot` notation to access values works with `struct` or `array<struct>` types.

The schema for field `number` in `item.fractimeData` is `string` and accessing it via `dot` notation returns an `array<string>` since `fractimeData` is an array.

Similarly, the schema for field `timePeriods` in `item.fractimeData` is `<array<struct<validFrom>>`, and accessing it via `dot` notation wraps it into another array, resulting in final schema of `array<array<struct<validFrom>>>`.

The error you get is because the `dot` notation can work on `array<struct>` but not on `array<array>`.

Hence, `flatten` the result from `item.fractimeData.timePeriods` to get back an `array<struct<validFrom>>` and then apply the `dot` notation.

```py
df_test_01 = spark.sql("""
 select flatten(item.fractimeData.timePeriods).validFrom as validFrom from v_test_df""")
df_test_01.collect()

"""
[Row(validFrom=['2021-08-03', '2021-08-03'])]
"""
```